# Is KafkaProducer fault tolerant?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We have a system which receives data from the users and pushes data to kafka and only when we are sure that the data has been pushed we send the user an "OK" response.
Since the new kafka is using async send(ProducerRecord,Callback), I wanted to know that if this send is crash resistant (fault-tolerant)?
My guess is that its most probably not,so how can I use it in sync mode? Or should I make the user wait until the callback is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Kafka's Design](https://kafka.apache.org/08/design.html) :

> Asynchronous send
>
> Batching is one of the big drivers of efficiency, and to enable batching the Kafka producer has an asynchronous mode that accumulates data in memory and sends out larger batches in a single request. The batching can be configured to accumulate no more than a fixed number of messages and to wait no longer than some fixed latency bound (say 100 messages or 5 seconds). This allows the accumulation of more bytes to send, and few larger I/O operations on the servers. Since this buffering happens in the client it obviously reduces the durability as any data buffered in memory and not yet sent will be lost in the event of a producer crash.